# dotNetRDF can not load System.EnterpriseServices

Tags: .net, dotnetrdf

I am trying to save a graph to a OpenLink `Virtuoso` database using `.net` and `dotNetRdf`. Connection is successfully created, but when I try to save graph, I get this message:

> *An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in dotNetRDF.Data.Virtuoso.dll
> Could not load file or assembly 'System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.*

My code is:

```
VirtuosoManager manager = new VirtuosoManager("localhost", 1111, "DB", "dba", "dba");    
manager.SaveGraph(store.Graphs.First());   // exception happens here
```

DotNetRDF and DotNetRDF.Data.Virtuoso are v2.6.0. Target framework is .NET Core 3.1.

I have tried everything that's suggested (copying .dll to GAC, enabling 32-bit applications in default pool, changing Visual Studio build settings...) but nothing worked.

Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi Đorđe. Can you update your question to add the version of dotNetRDF you are using and also the version of the .NET Framework that your application is compiled against please?

Comment: The error message is consistent with a mix of 32-bit and 64-bit components, i.e., a 32-bit component trying to load a 64-bit component, or a 64-bit component trying to load a 32-bit component. From what you've said, it *appears* that `dotNetRDF.Data.Virtuoso.dll` is trying to load `System.EnterpriseServices`, and that these are of different "bitness". `PATH` environment variables (`System` and `User`) are likely to be involved. Though you're connecting to Virtuoso, it plays no part in the error you're seeing, so I think that tag should be removed from your question.

Comment: So dotNetRDF.Data.Virtuoso is built only with .NET Framework as a target framework (it uses net40 as the TFM). I'm not entirely sure but I think that calling a .NET Framework assembly from .NET Core is not supported and that this could be what is causing the exception. FWIW, dotNetRDF.Data.Virtuoso doesn't have any direct dependency on System.EnterpriseServices either, so I'm not quite sure why it is this assembly being reported in the error. Can you rebuild targeting a version of .NET Framework?